# How to import downlodable product on different store using csv in magento2

Tags: magento2, downloadable, import-products

I want to import downloadable product in different store using csv in magento2

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to downloadable products and their import, the only difference they have from simple products in terms of attributes is the attribute downloadable_links.

[image]

The structure of the attribute is the following:

> price=link_price,url=https://url-to-the-file.com/file.pdf,downloads=number_of_downloads_available,group_title=title_of_the_downloadable_links,title=link_title

Where:

[image]

**Importing downloadable products**

To import products using native Magento 2 import, proceed to System > Import. Use the sample csv if you need and change it according. Change the store value for different store in csv

[Use sample downloadable product import Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13FemIzzexF5koAdQYjbcKscqoCfXyknYWkQkbSZGPsk/edit#gid=88985923)

I hope this will help

Comment: I want to import same product in different store where some attributes are different and some were same

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.4.4 if you want to import downloadable product with the file from your server, at first you need to put your file in folders "pub/media/downloadable/files/link_samples" and "pub/media/downloadable/files/links"

and the column "downloadable_links" in your csv file should contain
"title=FileTitle,sort_order=1,sample_type=file,price=0.000000,is_shareable=1,link_type=file,purchased_separately=0,group_title=Downloadable links,sample_file=mypdf.pdf,link_file=mypdf.pdf"

I hope it will help to save some time